# Ansible: How To Compare 1 Host's Services with Multiple Host's Services?

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-facts

I had an issue with comparing services for 2 server's with ansible. That is solved by the below yaml. My question is, how can I compare 1 host's service list with multiple host?

```
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false


  tasks:

  - name: Gather Service Facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Show all
    debug:
      var: services

  - name: Show difference
    ansible.utils.fact_diff:
      before: "{{ hostvars['test1.example.com'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
      after:  "{{ hostvars['test2.example.com'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
```

I changed the `after` section for looping through all of my hosts and compare those server's services with my first host which is in `before` section. My hosts are in my inventory file grouped with `selected_hosts` tag.

```
ansible.utils.fact_diff:
      before: "{{ hostvars['test1.example.com'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
      after: "{% for ip_address in groups['selected_hosts'] %}
                {{ hostvars[ip_address].services | to_nice_yaml }}
              {% endfor %}"
```

The problem here is, despite my yaml is correctly looping all of my servers from the inventory file, it won't show any differences for services. Example output is below:

```
+ NetworkManager-dispatcher.service:
+    name: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: inactive
+    status: enabled
+NetworkManager-wait-online.service:
+    name: NetworkManager-wait-online.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: stopped
+    status: enabled
+NetworkManager.service:
+    name: NetworkManager.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: running
+    status: enabled
+auditd.service:
+    name: auditd.service
+    source: systemd
+    state: running
+    status: enabled
```

**Note: I've only added some of the services in order to keep the simplicity**
The output doesn't print out any differences. It should print *-* symbol in front of the service name, as well as source, state and status.
How can I fix my yaml?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop over the task, rather than templating a loop in the `after` attribute. You also will probably want to run `fact_diff` on `localhost`. Maybe something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Gather Service Facts
    service_facts:

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Show difference
    ansible.utils.fact_diff:
      before: "{{ hostvars['node0.virt'].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
      after:  "{{ hostvars[item].services | to_nice_yaml }}"
    register: result
    loop: "{{ groups.all }}"

  - copy:
      dest: services.txt
      content: |-
        {% for item in result.results %}
        === {{ item.item }} ===

        {{ item.diff_text }}
        {% endfor %}
```

In my test environment, I have two hosts running identical services except that one system is running `darkhttpd`. The inventory file look like this:

```
all:
  vars:
    ansible_user: root
  hosts:
    node0.virt:
    node1.virt:
```

And the generated `services.txt` file looks like:

```
=== node0.virt ===


=== node1.virt ===

--- before
+++ after
@@ -93,11 +93,6 @@
     source: systemd
     state: unknown
     status: static
-darkhttpd.service:
-    name: darkhttpd.service
-    source: systemd
-    state: running
-    status: enabled
 dbus-broker.service:
     name: dbus-broker.service
     source: systemd
```